# Stanford NLP giving exception while running code

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run this code using file input and out put to another file:

```
import java.util.*;

import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentAnnotatedTree;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
//import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class TestCoreNLP {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out =  new PrintWriter("/home/aims/Desktop/outputNLP1");

    Properties props=new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos,lemma");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation;  
    String readString = "";
        //PrintWriter pw = null;
    BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader ( new FileReader ( "/home/aims/Desktop/testNLP" )  ) ;
        //pw = new PrintWriter ( new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( "/home/aims/Desktop/outputNLP", true )  )  ) ;      
    //String x = "";
        while  (( readString = br.readLine ())  != null)   {
            // pw.println ( readString ) ; 
             //String xx=readString;x=xx;//System.out.println("OKKKKK"); 
        annotation = new Annotation(readString);
 //System.out.print(readString);
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);    //System.out.println("LamoohAKA");
    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, out);
    out.println();
    out.println("The top level annotation");
    out.println(annotation.toShorterString());
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    if (sentences != null && !sentences.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.size (); i++) {
            CoreMap sentence = sentences.get(i);
            Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);//Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentAnnotatedTree.class);
            int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
            String sentimentName = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);

            out.println();
            out.println("The sentence is:");
            out.println(sentence.toShorterString());
            out.println();
            out.println("Sentiment of \n> \""+sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class)+"\"\nis: " + sentiment+" (i.e., "+sentimentName+")");
            out.println();
          }
    }

    IOUtils.closeIgnoringExceptions(out);
        }
        br.close (  ) ;
   // pw.close (  ) ;
    System.out.println("Done...");


  }

}
```

The input tp this code is:

```
I am glad you are here.
I will see you tomorrow.
I hate you.
Remember me!
I like ice-cream to utmost level of likeness.
```

When I ran the code using `Eclipse Neon`, I got the following error:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [2.4 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(RNNCoreAnnotations.java:83)
    at TestCoreNLP.main(TestCoreNLP.java:48)
```

Now I am not understanding why it is happening? What should I do to run this code successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't running the sentiment annotator or parser in your pipeline.  Here is a commandline call that shows running a pipeline and getting sentiment.  You can easily adapt it to Java code by setting the properties for your pipeline to match the ones specified by this call.

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse,sentiment -parse.binaryTrees -file example-sentence.txt -outputFormat text
```

You need to add the `parse` and `sentiment` annotators to your pipeline and you need to make sure that the `parse` annotator produces binary trees with the `parse.binaryTrees` property being set to true.

Here is some sample code that shows accessing sentiment:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SentimentExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Annotation document = new Annotation("I liked the first movie.  I hated the second movie.");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,sentiment");
    props.setProperty("parse.binaryTrees","true");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("---");
      System.out.println(sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));
      System.out.println(sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See this is command line. I have already said I am using Eclipse Neon. I f you know how to do it with Eclipse please suggest me.

Comment: I got it. Can you show me how to edit my code for a file. As after doing your suggestion I could read only a single line from a file. Where as I need to read a complete file. You see the input example of mine please.

Comment: are you there? can you help?

Comment: Thank you for your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Tree` object is null. However, why that occurs requires a deeper knowledge of what you are doing.

Just a guess, but it seems that the class you specify might not be in the sentence... So for instance, what you call `sentence.get`, there is no `SentimentAnnotatedTree.class` in the sentence to get, and so the method returns a null.